# Can't modify peripheral registers on the rp2040

Tags: rust, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico, peripherals

I'm scratching my head because I can't write and read some/most peripheral registers.
I'm using Rust here and the setup code from the rp2040-hal.

The following code tries to write `0x42` to the DMA's `CH0_READ_ADDR` register (`0x50000000`) and reads it back:

```rust
let ptr = (0x50000000 + 0x000) as *mut u16; // crtl
rprintln!("ptr {:p}", ptr);
unsafe {
    rprintln!("reg_before {:b}", ptr.read_volatile());
    ptr.write(0x42);
    rprintln!("reg_after {:b}", ptr.read_volatile());
}
```

This outputs:

```
ptr 0x50000000
reg_before 0
reg_after 0
```

This happens with several registers I tested. However, with the Watchdog's scratch register `WATCHDOG_SCRATCH0` (`0x4005800c`) (as suggested in the example on datasheet p.19), everything works as expected.

I thought that maybe that peripheral is not clocked or so, but I didn't find anything useful in the datasheet. Perhaps somebody has an idea on what's going wrong here.

#### Minimal working example:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

extern crate panic_rtt_target;

use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use rtt_target::{rprintln, rtt_init_print};
use rp2040_hal as hal;
use hal::pac;
use embedded_time::fixed_point::FixedPoint;
use rp2040_hal::clocks::Clock;

#[link_section = ".boot2"]
#[used]
pub static BOOT2: [u8; 256] = rp2040_boot2::BOOT_LOADER_W25Q080;

const XTAL_FREQ_HZ: u32 = 12_000_000u32;

#[entry]
fn entry() -> ! {
    let mut pac = pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let core = pac::CorePeripherals::take().unwrap();

    let mut watchdog = hal::Watchdog::new(pac.WATCHDOG);

    let clocks = hal::clocks::init_clocks_and_plls(
        XTAL_FREQ_HZ,
        pac.XOSC,
        pac.CLOCKS,
        pac.PLL_SYS,
        pac.PLL_USB,
        &mut pac.RESETS,
        &mut watchdog,
    )
    .ok()
    .unwrap();

    rtt_init_print!();
    rprintln!("Hello registers!");

    //let ptr = (0x4005800c) as *mut u16; // scratchreg
    let ptr = (0x50000000 + 0x000) as *mut u16; // dma ch0 read addr
    rprintln!("ptr {:p}", ptr);
    unsafe {
        rprintln!("reg_before {:b}", ptr.read_volatile());
        ptr.write(0x42);
        rprintln!("reg_after {:b}", ptr.read_volatile());
    }

    loop {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found out: It is about the resets of the chip.

The datasheet states in 2.14.1:

> Every peripheral reset by the reset controller is held in reset at power-up. It is up to software to deassert the reset of
> peripherals it intends to use.

So in this case the `DMA` bit of the `RESET` register has to be cleared:

```rust
pac.RESETS.reset.modify(|_, w| w.dma().clear_bit());
```

Afterwards the registers can be written to and read from as expected.

Comment: I just want to send you a HUGE thank you.  Your post here helped crystallize an identical issue I had on an ESP32-S3 chip, and eventually led me to find an undocumented register bit I had to de-assert to clear the ADC peripheral's RESET line before I could use it (bit 28 in `SYSTEM_PERIP_RST_EN0_REG` and  `SYSTEM_PERIP_CLK_EN0_REG` for anyone who stumbles here searching about the S3's ADC - see also `system_reg.h` in the framework).